# Colocar os items do menu dentro da div

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, flexbox

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
.top-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e07b39;
  height: 69px;
}
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style: none;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="top-content">
  <h1>LOGO</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
      <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Featured Content</a></li>
      <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Os meus itens estão fora da caixa do `div`. Já tentei meter um `padding-bottom`, mas eles não entram na caixinha.

Alguém tem uma melhor sugestão?

Comment: `height:auto`? Fora como?

Comment: @MagicHat veja como fica em https://jsfiddle.net/fretagi/xu85ptjr/51/ e verá que os items do menu estão fora da caixa `div`. não posso ter `height: auto` porque o projeto exige que seja `69px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece por causa do seu `h1` está com [comportamento padrão do tipo `block`](http://devfuria.com.br/html-css/elementos-inline-e-elementos-block-level/). Do jeito que está seu código, para exibir o `nav` dentro da sua `div` ao lado do `h1`, você poderia adicionar um `display: flex:` na sua classe `.top-content`.

Ficaria assim:

```css
.top-content {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #e07b39;
        height: 69px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }

.nav-list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        list-style: none;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-content">
      <div class="div-title">
        <h1>LOGO</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="div-nav">
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav-list">
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Featured Content</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">Location</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Seria esse o resultado esperado?

Foi uma sugestão minha de uma possível solução.

*Observer que coloquei um `align-items: center;` só pra deixar eles alinhados verticalmente.*

Comment: resultou, :) muito obrigado

Comment: se a tag `h1` fosse uma tag `img` será tinha tambem que utilizar um `display: flex`?

Comment: Do jeito que esta seu codigo sim ;)

Comment: Como seria outra maneira de compor o código?